# How to save twitter anomaly detection graph as png?

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I used package 'twitter/AnomalyDetection' to plot the anomaly. I was able to make the plot but have no idea how to save the plot as png image with dpi 600.
My code:

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%Y%m%d%H")
df <- df[, c("date", "var1")]
df <- AnomalyDetectionTs(df, max_anoms = 0.01, direction = "pos", plot = TRUE, e_value = T)
p <- df$plot
save(p, file = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/anomaly.png", dpi = 600)
```

> Error: objects 'p', '600' not found

Checked the structure of p, it was a list instead of a image.
Can anyone help solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Can u plot the graph?

Comment: If you are using r-studio, in the plots section where the plot appears, there is an export button to save the plot. If you want to do it using a code, use the `png` function or try `??png`.

Comment: Also, check this out for your reference : http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html

Comment: I can plot the graph in RStudio and I can save the image manually with "plot>export>save" method, but I think it would be better if I could save the image automatically in my scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to achieve this programatically:

```
df <- AnomalyDetectionTs(df, max_anoms = 0.01, direction = "pos", plot = TRUE, e_value = T)
png(file="C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/anomaly.png",units="in",res=600)
df$plot
dev.off()
```

Comment: I adjusted and ran the scripts again, still not be able to save the image. I can see the plot in RStudio though.

Comment: The error I got: "Error in png(file = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/anomaly.png", : unable to start png() device In addition: Warning messages: 1: In png(file = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/anomaly.png", : unable to allocate bitmap 2: In png(file = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/anomaly.png", : opening device failed "

Comment: @HW-Scientist try changing the path and store to another location. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093834/unable-to-open-png-device-in-loop