# How to find duplicates and remove one of them in a list

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames that contains some duplicates and I want to delete only one of them.
How should I write the code for that?

```
[[1]]
    term groups          y         data
1  value group3  -31.90134  383.4430531
2  value group3 -306.43674  308.9175450
3  value group3 -403.04776   13.3965355
4  value group3 -383.19765   33.1466333
5  value group3 -578.81867 -163.4743873
6  value group1 -404.39316   11.0511309
7  value group3  -31.90134  383.4430531

[[2]]
    term groups          y         data
1  value group3  -31.90123  383.4430531
2  value group3 -206.42674  208.9175450
3  value group3 -403.04776   12.2965256
4  value group2 -382.19765   33.1466323
5  value group2 -578.81867 -163.4743872
6  value group1 -404.29316   11.0511209
7  value group3  -31.90123  383.4430531
```

Comment: Yes exactly! - it works!
One last question then my whole script is finished - I created a list of ggplots and now I want to save every ggplot as a separate file
my code is the following:

Comment: ```
plots <- lapply(names(raphael_calc_sum),
         function(nm) {
           ggplot(raphael_calc_sum[[nm]], 
                  aes(x=group1, 
                      y=data, 
                      color = group2,
                      fill = group2)) +
             geom_bar(stat="identity",
                      position=position_dodge(0.9), 
                      color="black")+
             geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=calc-sd, 
                               ymax=calc+sd), 
                           position=position_dodge(0.9), 
                           color="black") 
```

Comment: `lapply(test, unique)` worked perfectly

Comment: YOu can save `+ggsave(filename = paste0(nm, '.png'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop over the `list` with `lapply` and get the `unique` rows

```
test1 <- lapply(test, unique)
```

---

Regarding the second case, if we have the plots in a `list`

```
names(plots) <- sub("\\.xlsx$", ".png", names(raphael_calc_sum))
lapply(names(plots), function(nm) plots[[nm]] + 
   ggsave(filename = file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", 
          nm )))
```

Comment: how can I change the path and the width?

Comment: @Raphael you could either `setwd(yourpath)` and then do this or use `lapply(file.path(yourpath, names(raphael_calc_sum)), function(nm) ..`

Comment: I want to use the second approach because I want to store the data in different folder. 
Unfortunately I get this error:
Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device
my code was the following:
`lapply(file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", names(raphael_calc_sum)), function(nm) plots[[nm]] + 
       ggsave( filename = paste0(nm, ".png")))`

Comment: Can you show `files <- file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", paste0(names(raphael_calc_sum), ".png"))` inside the function `filename = nm`

Comment: What if you save it as a pdf i.e. `.pdf` does it work

Comment: `[1] "C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_/raphael_2021_022.xlsx.png"
[2] "C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_/raphael_2021_023.xlsx.png"`

Comment: @Raphael i think the `.xlsx` may be the issue.  Can you do `files <- file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", sub("\\.xlsx$", ".png", names(raphael_calc_sum)))`

Comment: @Raphael I menat to use the previous comment iwith `sub`

Comment: Yes I ran it now and it looks good:
´[1] "C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/raphael_2021_022.png"
[2] "C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/raphael_2021_023.png"`

Comment: `lapply(file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", sub("\\.xlsx$", ".png", names(raphael_calc_sum))), function(nm) plots[[nm]] + 
       ggsave( filename = paste0(nm, ".png")))`
is this correct?
because I am getting still this error:
`Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device`

Comment: @Raphael I think the issue is that now the plots[[nm]]` wouldn't work because you haven't changed the names of plots.  Probablty do `names(plots) <- sub("\\.xlsx$", ".png", names(raphael_calc_sum))`  then use `lapply(names(plots), function(nm) plots[[nm]] + ggsave(filename = file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/barplot_tukey_", nm)))`

Comment: @Raphael i updated the post.  Can you try that

Comment: no still same error:
`Error in grDevices::png(..., res = dpi, units = "in") : unable to start png() device`

Comment: @Raphael is there any issues in `capabilities()`. Do you find `png` as TRUE

Comment: @Raphael Also, before running can you try `dev.off()`

Comment: yes png is TRUE and `dev.off()` leads to the error:`Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)`

Comment: @Raphael can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14093834/unable-to-open-png-device-in-loop) link.  It shows similar kind of error

Comment: I found the problem- I cannot put a prefix before the file - 
`names(barplots) <- sub("\\.xlsx$", ".png", names(raphael_calc_sum))
lapply(names(barplots), function(nm) plots[[nm]] + 
   ggsave(filename = file.path("C:/Users/Raphael/Desktop/barplot/", 
          nm )))`
This code works now!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: do you maybe know how i can change the height, width, dpi, ...? Because I cannot just add it after the filename